# automatically output a bunch of files, named after a parameter

Tags: c

Here is the situation. I have a parameter named `par` for example. In the program it ranges from 0.1 to 1.

```
for(par=0.1; par<1.001;par+=0.1)
```

I want to print out 10 separate files, the name should be named as `par-0.1.txt`, `par-0.2.txt`...

In each file, they have their output corresponding to the value of par, say:

```
fprintf(fp,"The par in this file is %lf", par);
```

How can I do this automatically? i.e name the files corresponding to the value of a changing parameter.

For your convenience, I put the program need to modify.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp; 
    double par;
    const char * filename= "par-0.1.txt";

    for(par=0.1; par<1.001; par+=0.1)
    {   
        fp = fopen(filename, "w");//I want a changing filename here!!
        fprintf(fp, "In this file, par is %lf", par);
        fclose(fp);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays of characters and [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Any reason why you are using float numbers for this? They are inaccurate and possibly slow, and best avoided unless you are doing advanced math. There is no reason why you can't use int here.  Example: `for(int par=1; par<1001; par++)  printf("%d.%d\n", par/10, par%10);`

Comment: @Lundin Yes, I am doing numerical calculation, par is truly a float-point number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing, you are initializing a string constant which are read only. You cannot change it the way you want.

For your requirements, you need a `char` array, and use `sprintf()`

```
char str[20];

sprintf(str, "par-%2.1f.txt", par);
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE * fp; 
  double par;
  char filename[128];

  for(par=0.1; par<1.001; par+=0.1)
  {   
    snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "par-%2.1f.txt", par);
    // not 100% sure how the float will get parsed in.
    fp = fopen(filename, "w");//I want a changing filename here!!
    fprintf(fp, "In this file, par is %lf", par);
    fclose(fp);
  }   
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've give you a vote up. Your answer also works great! thanks!